# Function to check all elements of an array

Tags: c, arrays, function

I want to make a function to check all elements of an array. But how to pass an array as parameter of a function correctly? I've tried to pass a pointer but it doesn't work, compiler don't even want to compile that code. What am I doing wrong? Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

int iseven(int *A); // prototype

int main(void)
{
  int i;

  int A[N]; // array to check

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    scanf("%d", &A[i]);

  i = iseven(*A);

  if (i == 1)
    printf("All numbers are even!\t\n");
  else
    printf("Not all numbers are even!\t\n");

  return 0;
}

int iseven(int *A)
{
  int i;
  int flag = 1;

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    if (((A[i] % 2) == 0) && (A[i] >= 2))
      continue;
    else
    {
      flag = 0;
      break;
    }

  return flag;
}
```

**gcc array.c -o array.exe**

```
 array.c: In function 'main':
 array.c:16:14: warning: passing argument 1 of 'iseven' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
        i = iseven(*A);
                   ^
 array.c:5:5: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'
 int iseven(int *A); // array to check
     ^
```

Comment: `i = iseven(*A);` --> `i = iseven(A);`

Comment: `i = iseven(A);` and retry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing argument makes pointer from integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162665/passing-argument-makes-pointer-from-integer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the function in the form

`i = iseven(A);`

Using `i = iseven(*A);` means that you are dereferencing the value at address `A` and passing it, which effectively means you are passing the first element of the array to the function.

This is the reason the compiler complains that the function receives an `int` when it was expecting an `int*`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!